# Swift: make debugging easier by being able to catch return value in defer statement

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, guard-statement

So I love declaring variables to hold return value and then return said variable on next line, thus making it easy to debug my code, I can just set a breakpoint at the return line and see what value it returns. I use this everywhere and it makes all my code so much easier to debug.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let cellCount = models.count
    return cellCount
}
```

But then you have the scenario where you have optionals and different conditions that have to be met in order for your method to makes sense. [The guard statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/guard-statement) is great for making sure some conditions are met, while not introducing [pyramids of doom](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/12/08/swift-optional-pyramids-of-doom.html).

But the problem with early returns is that you get at least two exit points (because `guard` requires a `return` in this context) from your method, which makes it harder to debug.

```
// Instantiate using dependency injection
private let reachability: ReachabilityProtocol
private let apiClient: APIClientProtocol

    // Returns true if could start login request, else false 
    func loginUser(username: String, password: String) -> Bool {
        defer {
             // Not possible, would be nice! Return value would be an implicitly declared variable
             // exaclty like the variables 'newValue' and 'oldValue' in property observers!
            print("return value: \(returnValue)")
        }
        guard reachability.isOnline && !username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty { return false }
        apiClient.loginUser(username, password: password)
        return true
    }
```

**It would be awesome if Swift 3.X would make [the defer statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/defer-statement) able to catch the return value, wouldn't it?**

This would make debugging so much easier, whilst still making use of `guard` and early returns. I have not insight what so ever in writing compilers etc, but it feels like this would not be *so* hard to implement in coming versions of Swift?

**Can you come up with a different way of achieving a single point to read return value of a method with multiple exit points**? (Without having to wait for my suggested improvement to `defer`?)

**Edit**:
My example above with the login is not a perfect example, sorry, why would I write code like that? Haha! But there are many other similar scenarios, maybe something like this, using `do-try-catch` also makes code hard to debug:

```
// We don't know the return value of this function! Makes it hard to debug!
func fetchUserByFirstName(firstName: String, andLastName lastName: String, fromContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> User? {
    defer {
         // Not possible, would be nice! Return value would be an implicitly declared variable
         // exaclty like the variables 'newValue' and 'oldValue' in property observers!
        print("return value: \(returnValue)")
    }

    guard !firstName.isEmpty else { print("firstName can't be empty"); return nil }
    guard !lastName.isEmpty else { print("lastName can't be empty"); return nil }
    // Imagine we have some kind of debug user... Does not really make sense, but good for making a point.
    guard firstName != "DEBUG" else { return User.debugUser }
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Users.entityName)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == \(firstName) AND lastName == \(lastName)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let user = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        return user
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error fetching user: \(error)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your suggested improvement to Swift to have `defer` capture the return value.

Here is something that will work, but it isn't perfect because it requires a little extra work (and code clutter), but you can do it manually by declaring `returnValue` with `let` at the top of your function, giving it the same type that the function returns.  Then, replace all of your `return <something>` with `returnValue = <something>; return returnValue`.

By declaring `returnValue` with `let`, Swift will let you know if you forget to assign `returnValue` before leaving the function.  So if you add a new `return` to your function, your function won't compile until you assign the `returnValue`.  You'll see the error: **error: constant 'returnValue' used before being initialized**.

```
func fetchUserByFirstName(firstName: String, andLastName lastName: String, fromContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> User? {
    let returnValue: User?
    defer {
        print("return value: \(returnValue)")
    }

    guard !firstName.isEmpty else { print("firstName can't be empty"); returnValue = nil; return returnValue }
    guard !lastName.isEmpty else { print("lastName can't be empty"); returnValue = nil; return returnValue }
    // Imagine we have some kind of debug user... Does not really make sense, but good for making a point.
    guard firstName != "DEBUG" else { returnValue = User.debugUser; return returnValue }
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Users.entityName)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == \(firstName) AND lastName == \(lastName)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let user = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        returnValue = user; return returnValue
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error fetching user: \(error)")
    }
    returnValue = nil; return returnValue
}
```

---

Alternatively (just brainstorming here...), put your function that has multiple exit points into an inner function, and then call it:

```
func fetchUserByFirstName(firstName: String, andLastName lastName: String, fromContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> User? {

    func innerFunc(firstName: String, andLastName lastName: String, fromContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> User? {

        guard !firstName.isEmpty else { print("firstName can't be empty"); return nil }
        guard !lastName.isEmpty else { print("lastName can't be empty"); return nil }
        // Imagine we have some kind of debug user... Does not really make sense, but good for making a point.
        guard firstName != "DEBUG" else { return User.debugUser }
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Users.entityName)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == \(firstName) AND lastName == \(lastName)")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        do {
            let user = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            return user.first as? User
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error fetching user: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    let returnValue = innerFunc(firstName, andLastName: lastName, fromContext: context)
    print("return value: \(returnValue)")
    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I usually do! :) thank you for taking the time and suggesting this though! :) I guess this is the only way at the moment...

Comment: Added second solution that is worse ;-)

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know it was possible to declare a function within a function! That is a very creative solutions!